# Pyathena is super slow compared to querying from Athena

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, amazon-sagemaker, pyathena

I run a query from AWS **Athena console** and takes 10s.
The same query run from **Sagemaker** using **PyAthena** takes 155s.
Is PyAthena slowing it down or is the data transfer from Athena to sagemaker so time consuming?

What could I do to speed this up?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just figure out a way of boosting the queries:

Before I was trying:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyathena import connect

conn = connect(s3_staging_dir=STAGIN_DIR,
             region_name=REGION)
pd.read_sql(QUERY, conn)
# takes 160s
```

Figured out that using a *PandasCursor* instead of a *connection* is way faster

```
import pandas as pd
pyathena import connect
from pyathena.pandas.cursor import PandasCursor

cursor = connect(s3_staging_dir=STAGIN_DIR,
                 region_name=REGION,
                 cursor_class=PandasCursor).cursor()
df = cursor.execute(QUERY).as_pandas()
# takes 12s
```

Ref: https://github.com/laughingman7743/PyAthena/issues/46

Comment: It seems like the time comments are reversed. The top should take longer i.e. 160s and the bottom takes 12s.

Comment: it's `pyathena.pandas.cursor` and not `pyathena.pandas_underscore_cursor` . Just a minor typo i understand but could save some potential searches along the way :-) @room13 @trudolf

Comment: you are right @RameshK unfortunately i cannot fix it. it says edits have to be at least 6 characters ^^